# Get data from access token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, net-http

How do you get the data from the access token?  It looks like I get the data encrypted. Do I need an key to decrypt it?  Here's the sample of the code.

```
x = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('http://www.asite.com/getinfo'), params)

@response = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(x.body) 

%>

<b>Got access token and access token is:</b><br>
<%=@response['access_token'] %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the JWT ruby gem

```
x = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('http://somesite.com/get_token'), params)
@res = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(x.body) 
id_token = @res['id_token']
id_data = JWT.decode id_token, 'secret', false
```